# Display unused categories in dropdown

Tags: categories

I have created a front end post with a form and I would like to have several categories for the user to choose between. But the problem is that the dropdown category only show those categories that are in use. I need it to show all categories even if they are not in use.

The code I'm using is following:

```
wp_dropdown_categories(   'show_option_none=Kategori&tab_index=4&taxo. nomy=register_vote_category' );
```

Comment: Are you using `wp_dropdown_categories`

Comment: Yes, I forgot to say that. I'm currently using

<p><?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_option_none=Kategori&tab_index=4&taxonomy=register_vote_category' ); ?></p>

Comment: You should add this info in an [edit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`wp_dropdown_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories) has a parameter specially to hide or to show empty categories.

> **hide_empty**
>
> (boolean) (optional) Show (0/False) or hide (1/True) category with no posts.
>
> Default: 1/True

You can simply just

```
 hide_empty=0
```

to your arguments

Comment: +1 This is most likely what the OP is looking for. I misread the question and thought he only wanted to show the empty categories ;-) ps You wrote `wp_list_categories` instead of  `wp_dropdown_categories`.